# SQL query to only return the rows that have the highest value in a certain column

Tags: mysql

I have a database I'm working on and I'm trying to figure out how to return every row that has the highest number in a specific column.

```
                        SELECT * MAX(version_group_id) = max_version_group_id
                        FROM table
                        GROUP BY max_version_group_id
                        ORDER BY max_version_group_id DESC;`;
```

I keep getting syntax errors and can't find out what is wrong here. I'm fairly new to sql.

Comment: You would clarify the question a lot if you add an example of input (the content of `table`) and the expected output (query result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not clear. If you want to select the rows whos column value is equal to the the highest column value of the table, use the following query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE version_group_id = (
  SELECT MAX(version_group_id)
  FROM table
)
```

It has a subquery that finds out which value is the highest.

---

The correct select syntax you try to implement is:

```sql
SELECT *, MAX(version_group_id) AS max_version_group_id
```

Comment: thanks, this query works almost perfectly! instead of only returning 1 result, how can i return every row of a specific `id`. so if i query the `id = 3`, ill get all the results back from that `identifier` each with a different `version_group_id` based on what the highest

Comment: @Shujin, I don't understand you. `id` is a primary key so if you query `select * from table where id = 3`, you will get at most 1 row.

Comment: @Shujin, do you need to group the rows by the `version_group_id` value and get 1 row from each group? If yes, how must the row be picked from a group?

Comment: right now i just need to sort them by `order` and i cant seem to get that working